# Outlook 2010 Add-ins context menu on attachments

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am doing a development in C# - outlook ad-ins.

I want to modify the context menu for the attachment. In other words, you have a right click menu coming for each attachment.

I don't want on Mail Item. 
I want on Mail Item > Item (Attachment)

I look forward for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Outlook 2007? There is an event that is raised when you click attachment right click:

`Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay`

You can work with that.